# Google chrome won't open -- there's not even an error (launched from terminal)

Tags: google-chrome

I've tried reinstalling Google Chrome several times and even downloading it directly from Google's website, but it never opens. When I go to the terminal and type "google-chrome" and "google-chrome-stable", neither one of them results in Google Chrome opening up.

It did at one point, but I'm not sure what caused it to stop working. It doesn't give me an error or anything when I launch it. Instead, it just hangs the cursor onto the next blank line (without a prompt, and as if it was actually running).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try purging and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the software center and download Chromium browser or in your terminal type

```
 Sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Chromium is the same thing as google chrome :)